# Not able to ssh remote host, Rhosts Authentication disabled

Tags: ssh

I have machine A and B, not able to ssh from server A to server B

I have copied id_rsa.pub from server A to server B  authorized_keys, in vice versa.

Even after copying, not able to ssh. Even with id_rsa not able to login server B

Facing issues as below

```
user1@serverA: ssh -vvv user1@serverB
Sun_SSH_2.4, SSH protocols 1.5/2.0, OpenSSL 0x1000218f
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: Default value for UseOpenSSLEngine is 0
debug1: Rhosts Authentication disabled, originating port will not be trusted.
debug1: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
```

Comment: Can you post more information how you did setup your keys and what devices are involved?

Comment: keys are generated via ssh-keygen and copied public key to remote server, folder/file permission of ..ssh folder are proper

Comment: You are connection to a solaris server?  It his the whole log? Because next step, as far as i know should be the actual connection to the ssh port. Do you rely on DNS resolution or is it a straight IP?

Comment: yes, rely on DNS resolution

Comment: Can you put in the IP address straight in the command? Did you manage to connect before? Which are the machines involved? Which steps where taken to come to this result?  It would really help if you update your question with all this vital information.

Comment: I have tried with IP address, same result. Am using solaris OS